# Problema para visualizar archivos creados con mkdir o repositorios clonados de github en el Escritorio de Windows

Tags: windows, windows10

Cuando intento clonar un repositorio de mi github o cuando quiero crear un directorio usando el comando mkdir no aparece en el escritorio, puedo acceder a esos directorios por comando, ya que figura como que están posicionados en el Escritorio, pero no los encuentro físicamente en ningún lado, probe desde el explorador de archivos viendo si estaban en oculto pero tampoco están. ¿Cuál podría ser el problema? y ¿Cuál la solución?

Comment: Necesitamos más información para poder ayudarte. Probaste refrescar el escritorio? Qué comandos usas y cómo se ve la consola? Dónde dice que estás y cuál es realmente la ruta del escritorio? Tal vez tengas varios discos, una carpeta de escritorio en cada uno y lo clonas en la que no es. Intenta escribir `explorer .` luego de clonar el repo para que se abra la misma carpeta.